# What is the probability of rolling a duplicate in the difference of a group of m d6 rolls from a group of n d6 rolls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Suppose you roll 3 white 6-sided dice (d6) and 3 black 6-sided dice. Any black dice numbers cancel out any corresponding white dice numbers. (The multiset of white dice numbers minus the multiset of black numbers)

Example:

- For white dice, you roll (1, 2, 2)
- For black dice, you roll (2, 3, 4)
- The result is (1, 2)

Example:

- White dice: (1, 1, 2)
- Black dice: (2, 5, 6)
- Result: (1, 1)

What is the probability that the result will have any duplicates? (Any repeating numbers)

General Question: For n white-dice, and m black dice, what is the probability that the difference of the white dice group subtracted by the black dice group will have any duplicates?

Comment: By duplicates, do you mean a result like $(1,1,2)$ or $(6,6)$? Do triples count as duplicates, like $(5,5,5)$? I'm a bit confused about your general question as well. What do you mean by difference? It looks like what you're doing is finding the difference between the set of white rolls and the set of black rolls, is that the "difference" you mean?

Comment: Does it come down to asking what is that probability that not all the numbers in the result will be unique?

Comment: @Jon Gourley By duplicates, I mean any repeating number. By difference I mean the multiset of white numbers minus the multiset of black numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $W$ denote the number of rolls with the white die that result in $1$.

Let $B$ denote the number of rolls with the black die that result in $1$.

Then the probability on a duplicate of $1$ equals:$$P(W=3\wedge B\leq1)+P(W=2\wedge B=0)=P(W=3)P(B\leq1)+P(W=2)P(B=0)$$

This can be found with binomial distribution.

The probability on a duplicate is $6$ times this probability because the events (a duplicate of $1$, a duplicate of $2$, et cetera) are mutually exclusive.